# 404 Error with 'get' fetch request from locally hosted server

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, express, crud

I am building a simple blog using the principles I learned [here](http://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) (CRUD app with Express and MongoDB). In order to edit previously published posts, I want to populate a text field with the contents of a blog post whose title is selected from a drop-down menu. That way I can easily make my changes and submit them.

I have written a basic 'put' fetch request that does absolutely nothing except report an error if something goes wrong:

```
fetch('articles', {method: 'put'})
        .then(  
            function(response) {  
                if (response.status !== 200) {  
                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +  response.status);  
                    return;  
                }

                // Examine the text in the response  
                response.json().then(function(data) {  
                    console.log(data);  
                });  
            }  
        )  
        .catch(function(err) {  
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);  
        });
```

Nothing goes wrong here, so `console.log(data)` is executed:

[image]

However, when I change 'put' to 'get' (and make no other changes), I get a 404 error:

[image]

How can it be that the 'get' fetch request causes a 404 error, but the 'put' request doesn't? I am hosting this app locally, so I'm running it from localhost:3000. The 'get', 'post', and 'put' operations in my server code look like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('articles').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        res.render('index.ejs', {articles: result});
    });
});

app.post('/articles', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('articles').save(req.body, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('saved to database');
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

app.put('/articles', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('articles')
    .findOneAndUpdate({title: 'test title'}, {
        $set: {
            title: req.body.title,
            body: req.body.body
        }
    }, {
        sort: {_id: -1},
        upsert: true
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

I would like to eliminate this 404 error so I can proceed with the ultimate reason I'm using the 'get' request: to populate a text field with the contents of a previously published blog entry. After I've made my edits, I plan to use the 'put' request to finalize the changes in MongoDB.

Please let me know whether you need any additional information. Your advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend replacing your screenshots of code and error messages with actual code/text so it's searchable & copy/pastable.

Comment: @Zed Did you update your code to include the recommended answer? In the screenshot you had before, you had `app.get('/')` and in the newly-added code, it shows `app.get('/articles')`, which is what the answer suggested – the question and answer are no longer coherent as a result.

Comment: @RushyPanchal I changed it back to `app.get('/')` to stay consistent with the title

Comment: @Zed Thank you – you shouldn't really update a question with an answer because if someone comes along later on, they won't see the actual error you were having. Now, however, anyone looking at this question will see the issue and the answer and it should be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a `GET /articles` route; you do have a `GET /` route, however.

If you want `GET /articles` to work, you should change the first argument to `app.get` to `'/articles'`.

Comment: After making that change, I got the following error in Chrome console:  `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. Your thoughts?

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to do a GET and parsing it as JSON, but you're getting back HTML instead. I think you need a `GET /articles` route that returns JSON and a `GET /` route that returns your HTML.

Comment: I'm new to this, so please forgive my ignorance! How would I go about formatting the GET request so that it returns JSON?

Comment: You'll format the GET request the same way you're doing the POST request, only you'll use GET.

Or do you mean to ask how you'd format the GET _response_? You'll fetch the data the same as you do for `/`, but then instead of plugging articles into your template, you'll just `res.send(articles)`.